# if value is not empty, then insert mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql like this (the id is primary key):

```
 id | name | age
 1 |  John | 46
 2 |       | 56
 3 | Jane  | 25
```

Now I want to update the name only if this is empty. If the value is not empty it should duplicate the row with a new id else it should update the name.

I thought it could be done with an if-statement but it doesn't work.

```
if((select `name` from `table1` where `id` = 3) = '',
update `table1` set `name`='ally' where `id` = 3, 
insert into `table1` (`id`,`name`,`age`) values 
(4, 'ally', select `age` from `table1` where `id` = 3))
```

EDIT:

With Spencers answer I made it working using an if in the code. (However I would still like a way to do just a single mysql query).

```
db.set_database('database1')
cursor = db.cursor()

query = "select IF(CHAR_LENGTH(name)>0,1,0) from table1 where id = {0}".format(id)
cursor.execute(query)
val1 = cursor.fetchone()

if val1[0]:
    query = "INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`,`name`,`age`) SELECT {0},{1},`age` FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = {2}".format(new_id, name, id)
    cursor.execute(query)
else:
    query = "update `table1` set `name` = '{0}' where `id` = {1}".format(name, id)
    cursor.execute(query)

db.commit()
```

Comment: totally pointless. just use `insert ... on duplicate key update`.

Comment: @MarcB, no insert ... on duplicate key update is not the solution, because it will always be a duplicate key (the id is the primary key) only when for the second or more times it is updated it needs to duplicate the row.

Comment: put a unique index on the name field, then?

Comment: @MarcB the names are not unique

Comment: Why not make life easy for yourself? First test if a certain id has an empty name, then decide in PHP or whatever language you use if you need to update or insert.

Comment: @TomasoAlbinoni I wanted to find a clean and fast solution without round-trips. But maybe it isn't possible this way.

Comment: do you solved your problem?

Comment: @EntGriff I solved it by using an if-statement in the python code. So yes it is working and no I didn't find the solution I was looking for (pure mysql statement). But I'll place the working solution on top.

Comment: @user3605780 - if you can call mysql procedure from python - i can write simple procedure with this logic

Answer (score 1):

If you make like this :

```
select t.*, 
if( 
    EXISTS(select n.name from table1 n where n.id = 2 and NULLIF(n.name, '') is  null) , 
    'true', 
    'false' 
  ) from table1 t
```

if statement returns "true", becouse in your table exist row where id =2 and name is empty.

like this example, You can edit your query :

```
if(
     EXISTS(select n.name from table1 n where n.id = 3 and NULLIF(n.name, '') is  null),
     update `table1` set `name`='ally' where `id` = 3, 
    insert into `table1` (`id`,`name`,`age`) values 
  (4, 'ally', select `age` from `table1` where `id` = 3)
)
```

Comment: this returns a syntax error. I think like spencer said it can only be used inside a stored procedure.

Comment: if you execute only this snippet - of course it returns error, i thinked you have it inside procedure or inside function and i only edited your query snippet, becouse if statement in your code was not correctly, and now it is right

Answer (score 1):

`IF` is not a valid MySQL statement (outside the context of a MySQL stored program).

To perform this operation, you'll need two statements.

Assuming that a zero length string and a NULL value are both conditions you'd consider as "empty"...

To conditionally attempt an update of the `name` field, you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE table1 t
   SET t.name = IF(CHAR_LENGTH(t.name)>0,t.name,'ally')
 WHERE t.id = 3 ;
```

The `IF` expression tests whether the current value of the column is "not empty". If it's not empty, the expression returns the current value of the column, resulting in "no update" to the value. If the column is empty, then the expression returns 'ally'.

And you'd need a separate statement to attempt an INSERT:

**EDIT**

This isn't right, not after a successful `UPDATE`... of the existing row. The attempt to INSERT might need to run first,

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id,name,age)
SELECT 4 AS id, 'ally' AS name, t.age
  FROM table1 t
 WHERE t.id = 3
   AND CHAR_LENGTH(t.name)>0;
```

We need a conditional test in the WHERE clause that prevents a row from being returned if we don't need to insert a row. We don't need to insert a row if the value `'ally'` ...

---

The use of `CHAR_LENGTH >0` is a convenient test for string that is not null and is not zero length. You could use different test, for however you define "empty". Is a single space in the column also considered "empty"?)

Comment: The conditional logic for the UPDATE is sound; I had a solution for the INSERT, but after reviewing it, it's not right. We can perform a conditional insert, using a WHERE clause that prevents a row from being returned when we don't need to do an insert. I'm thinking now, we might need to attempt the INSERT first, and have that not insert a row if the `name` in row id=3 is empty, *before* we do the UPDATE.

Comment: The if char_length> 0 works as a select statement. However as you said this won't work inside an IF statement. I think I have two options. First select the boolean and then do an if-statement in Python or create a mysql stored program. I never created a stored program before. If this is easy it might be faster then two queries in Python since it doesn't need a round-trip. What do you suggest?

Comment: One extra round trip to the database per transaction isn't really worth a MySQL stored program, not for singleton transactions. If you're processing a gazillion rows, you need a way to do it more efficiently than row by agonizing row. If you've got a file to be processed, use LOAD DATA to load into the database; then you process the whole thing as a set. An extra round trip doesn't really hurt performance, it's processing rows one at a time that kills performance. I can't make a recommendation without knowing what you are really trying to achieve. This is rather unusual specification.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me where you are getting the `id` values from, the `3` and the `4` shown in the example statement. How is it you know that the row you want to update is `id=3` and how do you know the row you want to insert is `id=4`, that's the thing that I don't really understand, which is why the specification strikes me as unusual. (The CHAR_LENGTH is just one option. The question is, what exactly do you mean by "empty". (There is no "IS EMPTY" condition in MySQL.) To me, it sounds like "empty string". But if the column can be NULL, likely that's considered empty as well.)

Comment: The id is a value which comes from the code. And I generate a new one if I insert a new row. The column will always be empty or a new row needs to be inserted, so the char_length option works fine. I implemented it with an if-statement in Python. For performance it didn't really matter I was just looking for a clean solution.